# How can I duplicate standard input (stdin) to multiple subprocesses in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I want to redirect stdin to multiple scripts, in order to test an in-development git hook while leaving the old one in place. I know I should use `tee` somehow, I don't see how I can use the basic `>`, `<` and pipe `|` redirection features of bash to do this. Furthermore, how can I redirect the stdin of a script? I don't want to use `read`, because that only reads one line at a time and I'd have to re-execute all subprocesses for each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use tee with normal files (possibly temp files via `mktemp`), then `cat` those files to your various scripts. More directly, you could replace those normal files with Named Pipes created with `mkfifo`. But you can do it in one pipe using Bash's powerful Process Substitution `>( cmd )` and `<( cmd )` features to replace the file `tee` expects with your subprocesses.

<s>Use `<&0` for the first tee to get the script's stdin.</s> Edit: as chepner pointed out, tee by default inherits the shell's stdin.

The final result is this wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +o pipefail
tee >(testscipt >> testscript.out.log 2>> testscript.err.log) | oldscript
```

Some notes:

- use `set +o pipefail` to *disable* Bash's pipefail feature if it was previously enabled. When enabled, Bash will report errors from within the pipe. When disabled, it will only report errors of the last command, which is what we want here to keep our testscript invisible to the wrapper (we want it to behave as if it was just calling oldscript to avoid disruption.
- redirect the stdout of testscript, otherwise it'll be forwarded to the the next command in the pipeline which is probably not what you want. Redirect stderr too while you're at it.
- Any number of `tee`s can be pipe chained like this to duplicate your input <s>(but don't copy the `<&0` stdin redirection from the initial one)</s> (initial `<&0` has been removed)

Comment: Thanks to http://www.vincebuffalo.com/2013/08/08/the-mighty-named-pipe.html for the process substitution examples.

Comment: The `<&0` is redundant; `tee` already inherits standard input from the shell.

Comment: I wanted to be able to select a part of `vim` buffer, that is a SQL query, and replace it with the query itself and its result. For that I needed a command that takes SQL query as input, and produces the SQL query itself plus result. The command I thought up is: `tee >(cat >&2) | psql`.